# Check if part och string exists in "part of array"

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

I have a loop which uses `array_push()` to insert new values into my array. Sometimes, a new value which is going to be *"pushed in"* looks similar to an existing value. Therefore, the array might include *"duplicates"*, which are not exactly similar.

I've tried using `in_array()`, but it looks like the values have to be exactly similar to each other.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I could write an if-statement to avoid "duplicates" in my array.

This is a simplified version of my script:

```
for ($y=0; $y<=1000; $y++) {
    $array = array();
    array_push($feed, 
        array(
            "name" => $name,
            "line" => $line,
             "duration" => $duration
       )
    )
}
```

I would like to check if `$line` is similar to existing ones before I push the array. The lines are collected from another script. By smilar I mean: the 10 first characters are equal `substr($line, 0, 10)`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot to mention that the array_push is part of a big loop... I'll update my example!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this codes. such as

```
foreach($something as $value){
    if(!in_array($value, $liste, true)){
        array_push($liste, $value);
    }
}
```

I am sure it take only unique value in your array. Best of luck!